# AngularJS routing based on scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

[image]

I'm using Angular for a project, and was wondering if it is possible to use Angular's routing functionality (or that of a 3rd party library such as ui-router) to control navigation in a scenario as demonstrated above.

If so, is it possible to have alternative routes in addition to this (e.g. a modal opens up presenting itself as a page)?

Comment: Have you tried using $anchorscroll? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: @flybear I've come across it, but it doesn't seem to have SEO-friendly URLs or the history API, and I'm unsure as to how I'd implement the second part of the question using it

Comment: I think you will have to implement custom routing for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your subsectons into different templates with different states and then use `ui-router`'s [animation API](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate) to do a transition between states. Here's an example impementation.

**In your route config**

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider  

  .state('firstSubpage', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<div class="full-page">\
       <h2>Page One</h2>\
       <a ui-sref="secondSubpage">Next page</a>\
    </div>'
  })
  .state('secondSubpage', {
    url: '/page2',
    template: '<div class="full-page two">\
       <h2>Page Two</h2>\
       <a ui-sref="firstSubpage">Next page</a>\
    </div>'
  })

}]);
```

**In your CSS**

```
/* set height explicitly on ui-view */
div[ui-view] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  /*padding-left: 0px;*/  
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  /*padding-left: 100px;*/
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
```

And then you just need an element with `ui-view` in your home template.

[Here's a working example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1W0TDDxDuFUWxIWVvtq?p=preview).